# HttpClient SendAsync Object disposed exception when request version is Http 1.1 passes when it is HTTP 1.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using HttpClient to send a post request to my service , where when user is unauthorized 401 status code is returned on receiving that i throw an exception from my client code, but once this use case is done my client program  keeps throwing , i get an exception when i call HttpClient.SendAsync() method.

> System.ObjectDisposedException occurred Message: A first chance
>   exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
>   System.dll Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.

and finally i get -

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message=Error while copying content to a stream.
  HResult=-2146233088
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Error while copying content to a stream.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       _HResult=-2146232800
       _message=The read operation failed, see inner exception.
       HResult=-2146232800
       IsTransient=false
       Message=The read operation failed, see inner exception.
       Source=System.Net.Http
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
            at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.StartRead()
       InnerException: System.Net.WebException
            _HResult=-2146233079
            _message=The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
            HResult=-2146233079
            IsTransient=false
            Message=The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
                 at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
            InnerException:
```

I have to in fact restart service to get proper response again.

Above behavior happens only if HttpRequestMessage.Version is set to HttpVersion.Version11 but when HttpVersion.Version10 everything works fine, following is a sample code i created to reproduce same , any insights on why this happens?

```
class Program {
        static HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler{Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials};           

        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                try {
                    Main2().Wait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task Main2() {
            var client1 = new HttpClient(handler,false);
             client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = CacheControlHeaderValue.Parse("no-cache");
             HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/RestFramework/AuditEventService/AuditEvent") {
                 Content = new StringContent("sdad"),
                 Version = HttpVersion.Version11

             };
           request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                response = await client1.SendAsync(request); // i am expecting a 401 status code, this line cause issue
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var statusCode = response.StatusCode; 
                    throw new Exception(statusCode.ToString());
                }
            } finally {
                client1.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

my web api service  returns a 401 for the request which i am passing, if i put a sleep in my filter code mentioned below everything works fine ,the code for filter looks below-

```
internal class IntegrateWindowsAuthenticationFilter : IActionFilter {

        /// <summary>
        /// user groups
        /// </summary>
        public IList<string> UserGroups { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// user names
        /// </summary>
        public  IList<string> UserNames { get; set; }

        #region IActionFilter Members

        /// <summary>
        ///     Executes the action filter asynchronous.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="actionContext">The action context.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
        /// <param name="continuation">The continuation.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation) {
            //Thread.sleep(1000) // this make things work with http 1.1
            var output = false;
            if (UserGroups != null) {
                foreach (var group in UserGroups) {
                    output = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(group);
                    if (output) {
                        return continuation();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (UserNames != null) {
                foreach (var user in UserNames) {
                    output =
                        actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name
                            .Equals(user,
                                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    if (output) {
                        return continuation();
                    }
                }
            }

            var outcome = new OperationOutcome();
            outcome.Issue.Add(new IssueComponent {
                Details = Constants.UnauthorizedAccess
            });
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }

        #endregion

        #region IFilter Members

        /// <summary>
        ///     Gets a value indicating whether [allow multiple].
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///     <c>true</c> if [allow multiple]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        public bool AllowMultiple {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: That's not 11 and 10. It's HTTP 1.1, the default, and 1.0, the older standard. *All* instances of HttpClient use 1.1 unless instructed otherwise. If you have a problem, it's your code that causes it

Comment: For example, you are using a *static* instance which you *dispose* in case of error. That almost guarantees an exception if you don't take care to *always* reinitialize the static field. Just *don't* use `Dispose` like this, HttpClient is meant to be reused

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i should have formatted code before posting, i am not using that static instance in code, i always reinitialize , i have tried keeping a static instance as well( and not disposing it)  but that as well did not work, yes my code could be issue need to know that problem only.

Comment: Let's rephrase. Everyone is using HttpClient with HTTP v1.1 without issues. You *didn't* post where the exception occurs though, not even the complete exception - including the call stack. That `Error while copying content to a stream.` is very suspicious. The content stream is used when writing a request or reading a response. What does the service that `just returns 401` do? Why in a filter? Does it terminate the request or response stream prematurely? Did you try to create a service that returns a 401 from its controller?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos edited the question thanks for input

Comment: @ankush - your exception stack is not complete..

Comment: @Ramesh this is what i get when i copy exception to clipboard last innerexception is null

Comment: @ankush - I am not seeing Main2 in the stack. So, What happens if you are using just the sync version instead of async? Is the stack trace shows which method / line in Main2 is causing the exception.

Comment: @Ramesh   response = await client1.SendAsync(request); causes the exception

Comment: @ankush you didn't add code for your web service implementation (AuditEventService/AuditEvent). Can you please add it.

Comment: I am also facing same issue as shared by Ankush. I am able to repro it by just running first program shared by Ankush. I am not sure as why HttpVerion10 works but HttpVersion11 doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The root cause is a problem in the .NET Framework HTTP stack. The .NET Framework bug has not been fixed. The repro is sensitive to race conditions.

Problem has been discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24683) and seems to be an unresolved .Net Framework bug.

Possible workaround would be to use HTPP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1, or to use HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead option in the .SendAsync call. This would, in most cases, bring race conditions to pass.